# I can not transfer data between two activities

Tags: android, android-activity, appcompatactivity

I start learning Android programming recently. I have a problem with transferring data between two activities. In the first activity, some EditTexts take information from the user and the btn_apply button should save them in a list. The btn_show button should show the students_lastnames on the second activity but my code only shows the last last_name repeatedly. I don't know what is the problem?

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.mysixthandroidapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        EditText txt_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        EditText txt_id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_lastname);
        EditText txt_filed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_field);
        EditText txt_university = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_university);
        EditText txt_startyear = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_startyear);
        
        Button btn_apply = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_apply);
        Button btn_show = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_show);

        Student std = new Student();

        TextView txt_result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_result);

        final ArrayList<Student> students  = new ArrayList<Student>();
        
        btn_apply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                std.setStudent_name(txt_name.getText().toString());
                std.setStudent_lastname(txt_id.getText().toString());
                std.setStudent_field(txt_filed.getText().toString());
                std.setStudent_university(txt_university.getText().toString());
                std.setStudent_startyear(txt_startyear.getText().toString());
                students.add(std);

            }
        });


        btn_show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                Bundle arg = new Bundle();
                arg.putSerializable("STUDENT", (Serializable)students);
                myIntent.putExtra("BUNDLE", arg);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Second Activity:

```
package com.example.mysixthandroidapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Intent intent  = getIntent();
        Bundle arg = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
        ArrayList <Student> students_list = (ArrayList <Student>)arg.getSerializable("STUDENT");
        TextView txt_list = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_list);


        for(int i = 0 ; i < students_list.size() ; i++){

            txt_list.setText("student: "+i + students_list.get(i).getStudent_lastname() + "\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Student Class:

```
package com.example.mysixthandroidapp;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String Student_name;
    private String Student_lastname;
    private String Student_field;
    private String Student_university;
    private String Student_startyear;


    public void setStudent_name(String name) {

        Student_name = name;
    }
    public void setStudent_lastname(String lname) {

        Student_lastname = lname;
    }
    public void setStudent_field(String field) {

        Student_field = field;
    }
    public void setStudent_university(String university) {

        Student_university = university;
    }
    public void setStudent_startyear(String startyear) {

        Student_startyear = startyear;
    }


    public String getStudent_name() {

        return Student_name;
    }
    public String getStudent_lastname() {

        return Student_lastname;
    }
    public String getStudent_field() {

        return Student_field;
    }
    public String getStudent_university() {

        return Student_university;
    }
    public String getStudent_startyear() {

        return Student_startyear;
    }



}
```

Comment: Is Student class Serializable?

Comment: it should be? :) How?

Comment: Yes, it should be. Check how to make a class Serializable. Also look at the answer given, it provides alternatives.

Comment: `public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {` - Done

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert your object to JSON and pass it through intent. In the new Activity convert the JSON to an object.

In your `build.gradle`, add this to your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:*Version*'
```

In your Activity, convert the object to json-string:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String myJson = gson.toJson(vp);
intent.putExtra("myjson", myjson);
```

In your receiving Activity, convert the json-string back to the original object:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourObject ob = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("myjson"), YourObject.class);
```

**For Kotlin it's quite the same**

Transfer data

```
val gson = Gson()
val intent = Intent(this, YourActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("identifier", gson.toJson(your_object))
startActivity(intent)
```

Received by

```
val gson = Gson()
val yourObject = gson.fromJson<YourObject>(intent.getStringExtra("identifier"), YourObject::class.java)
```

**2nd Way**

- Implementing Parcelable

  Implementing Serializable

  Using a light-weight event bus library of some sort (for example,
  Greenrobot's EventBus or Square's Otto)

**[Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable)** - fast and Android standard, but it has lots of boilerplate code and requires hard-coded strings for reference when pulling values out the intent (non-strongly typed).

**[Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable)** - close to zero boilerplate, but it is the slowest approach and also requires hard-coded strings when pulling values out the intent (non-strongly typed).

**[Event Bus](https://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/)** - zero boilerplate, fastest approach, and does not require hard-coded strings, but it does require an additional dependency (although usually lightweight, ~40 KB)

I posted a very detailed comparison around these three approaches, including efficiency benchmarks.